# How can I convert an integer like "170526" into its equivalent date (in this case 05/26/17)?

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

In my spreadsheet, I've got a bunch of dates formatted weird like:

```
170526
180921
181002
181002
181021
```

I'd like to use a formula and convert those over to:

```
05/26/17
09/21/18
etc.
```

where the first two digits are the year, middle two is the month, and the last two are the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A), MID(A1:A, 3, 2)&"/"&RIGHT(A1:A, 2)&"/"&LEFT(A1:A, 2), ))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A), 
 TEXT(("20"&REGEXREPLACE(""&A1:A, "\d{2}(\B)", "$0-")), "mm/dd/yy"), ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=("20"&REGEXREPLACE(""&A1,"\d{2}(\B)","$0-"))*1
```

- `REGEX` to `REPLACE` border of every two digits with `-`
- `"20"&` to add year
- `*1` to convert string to date value.
- Format>Number>Date